# Update asp:label on another page? 

Tags: c#, asp.net, label

I'm working with an asp.net website using C# in the background. I would like to be able to update an asp:label on a page, lets say **Page1.aspx**. I want this be updated depending on the outcome of a function in a class (.cs) in other folder. This could be **behind.cs**.

**behind.cs**

```
*some other code is here*
bool correct = false;
try
{
    if (_myConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        _myConn.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    if (Convert.ToInt32(myCommand.Parameters["@SQLVAR"].Value) < 1)
    {
        "Invalid Login" // I want to be the text of lblMessage.Text
    }
    else
    {
        correct = true;                 
    }
    _myConn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    "Error connecting to the database" // I want to be the text of lblMessage.Text
}
return correct;
```

**page1.aspx**

```
<asp:label runat="server" ID="lblMessage" cssClass="error"></asp:label>
```

How can I update the asp:label on **page1.aspx* from **behind.cs**??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly access the label from another class.
You can write a `TryLogin` function that has an out parameter with the error message.

In Page1.cs

```
protected void BtnLogin_Clicked(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    string errMess;
    if(!Behind.TryLogin(out errMess)
       lblMessage.Text = errMess;
}
```

In behind.cs

```
public static bool TryLogin(out string errMess)
{
  *some other code is here*
  errMess = null;
  bool correct = false;
  try
  {
    if (_myConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        _myConn.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    if (Convert.ToInt32(myCommand.Parameters["@SQLVAR"].Value) < 1)
    {
        errMess = "Invalid Login" // I want to be the text of lblMessage.Text
    }
    else
    {
        correct = true;                 
    }
    _myConn.Close();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    errMess = "Error connecting to the database" // I want to be the text of lblMessage.Text
  }
  return correct;
}
```

Comment: Perfectly explained. Thanks a lot. =]

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way for you to access the `page1.lblMessage` member from code in `behind.cs`. There are two ways to handle it:

- For normal data, return a `string` from the code in `behind.cs` that the calling function in `page1` assigns to `lblMessage`.
- For exceptional events (such as the invalid login in your example) throw an exception in your code. In the code calling the `behind.cs` method, catch the exception and assign the text to `lblMessage`.

In your code you should add the following in your catch block:

```
throw new MyException("Error connection to the database", e);
```

You will have to create a `MyException` class first. Then in the calling code,  `catch(MyException)` and display the text. You can also handle the `Page.Error` event if you want to handle all exceptions in one place of the page code. The `e` parameter to the `MyException` constructor is meant as supplying the underlying exception as an `InnerException`. When debugging it is always useful to keep the original, technically informative exception around.